# Проверка интернет соединения с помощью urllib

Tags: python, urllib

Накидал такую вот функцию проверки интернет соединения.

**Основной вопрос внизу.**

```
def network_connection_check(link):
    for timeout in [1, 3, 5]:
        try:
            if not link.startswith('http'):
                link = 'http://' + link
            print(link)
            urllib.request.urlopen(link, timeout=timeout)
            return True
        except:
            return False


print(network_connection_check('i.ytimg.com'))
print(network_connection_check('google.com'))
```

Вывод:

```
http://i.ytimg.com
False
http://google.com
True
```

upd:
Да, как заметил @CrazyElf этот сайт действительно возвращает код 400. Менять весь топик не буду, но вопрос остаётся: **будет ли конкатенация `http://` универсальной, даже в случаях, если протокол сайта `https://`?**

Comment: Если вы не знаете, какой протокол должен быть, значит и сделать с этим ничего не получится

Comment: Просто во всех случаях ввода условного 'google.com' достаточно, почему это не срабатывает с этой библиотекой?

Comment: Когда вы вводите условный 'google.com', выполняется автоматическая конкатенация с протоколом `http://`

Comment: @andreymal а если адрес с протоколом `https://`?

Comment: Всё равно выполняется конкатенация именно с протоколом `http://`, а потом при первом запросе сервер присылает редирект на https-версию себя

Comment: Хотя вот новая версия браузера Chrome 90, которая вышла как раз сегодня, изменила протокол по умолчанию с `http://` на `https://` — теперь сперва будет пробоваться https, а если его открыть не получится, то только после этого браузер произведёт откат до http

Comment: @andreymal  а если просто вручную конкатенировать с одним из этих протоколов, будет ли она автоматом редиректить в случае несоответствия?

Comment: Если сервер действительно пришлёт редирект, то да, urllib по умолчанию обрабатывает редиректы

Comment: «Добавил в код» — куда конкретно?

Comment: @type49 Не может не работать тот `if`. Вы точно сохранили файл и запускаете обновлённую версию скрипта?

Comment: @CrazyElf - обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте нормальную обработку `Exception` с выводом его на печать:

```
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        return False
```

Вывод:

```
http://i.ytimg.com
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
False
http://google.com
True
```

Можете проверить в консоли браузера, этот сайт действительно возвращает 404.

**Update**: Вариант кода, который проверяет по очереди `http` и `https`, если префикс не задан. Но для этих сайтов в общем-то ничего не меняется:

```
import urllib
from urllib import request

def try_urlopen(link):
    try:
        print(link)
        urllib.request.urlopen(link)
        return True
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    return False

def network_connection_check(link):
    if not link.startswith('http'):
        for prefix in ['http://', 'https://']:
            if try_urlopen(prefix+link):
                return True
        return False
    else:
        return urllib.request.urlopen(link)

print(network_connection_check('i.ytimg.com'))
print(network_connection_check('google.com'))
```

Вывод:

```
http://i.ytimg.com
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
https://i.ytimg.com
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
False
http://google.com
True
```

Comment: Точно, просто уже запутался. Но вопрос вот в чём: будет ли конкатенация `http://` универсальной, даже в случаях, если протокол сайта `https://`?

Comment: @type49 А что вам мешает попробовать оба варианта по очереди? Хотя нормальные сайты должны обрабатывать оба варианта и перенаправлять браузер на более актуальную версию по мнению создателей сайта.

Comment: @type49 Добавил код с проверкой обоих вариантов

Comment: Уже отметил и плюсанул, спасибо, в общем!