# Кириллица в url

Tags: python, unicode, кириллица, urllib

Приходят в `urllib.request.urlopen` всяческие ссылки, в том числе содержащие кириллицу. Ну и в этом случае выбивает `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters`. Энкод, декод и прочее не работает. Как можно решить?

```
link = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1270679/Проверка-интернет-соединения-с-помощью-urllib'

urllib.request.urlopen(link)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389572

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from requests.utils import requote_uri
quote_link = requote_uri(link)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за этот метод, плюсанул, но, как выяснилось функция идёт дальше и спотыкается даже с переведенной в правильный формат ссылкой. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @type49, задайте новый вопрос

Comment: Вы в этом уверены? После `requote_uri` там нет чистой кириллицы. У меня всё работает нормально.

Comment: Да, проверил в чистом файле. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1270772/check-hostname-requires-server-hostname-при-кириллице-в-ссылке