# check_hostname requires server_hostname при кириллице в ссылке через VPN

Tags: python, requests

```
link = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1270679/Проверка-интернет-соединения-с-помощью-urllib'
resp = requests.get(link , timeout=3)
```

При наличии кириллицы в ссылке выбивает с
`ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname`.

upd: выбивает только при подключенном vpn. Но тот же гугл.ком с vpn работает нормально.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66642705/7485582

Comment: В предыдущем вопросе вы использовали `urllib`, а не `requests`